# Construction of $r$ indepentent units for an order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field over $\mathbb{Q}$ (ie. $K = \mathbb{Q}(\vartheta)$) and $R$ an order of $K$.

In $\mathbb{C}$: $f_\vartheta = \prod_{i=1}^n (X-\varrho^{(i)})$. By convention: $\varrho^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $i \le r_1$ and $\varrho^{(i)} = \overline{\varrho^{(i+r_2)}}$ for $r_1 \lt i \le r_2 := \frac{n-r_1}{2}$. The homomorphism $\psi_j: \mathbb{Q}[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, X \mapsto \varrho^{(j)}$ induces a homomorphism $\varphi_j: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \varphi_j(\overline{X}) = \varrho^{(j)}$. For $\alpha \in L$ let $\alpha^{(j)} := \varphi_j(\alpha)$.

Let $r := r_1+r_2-1$ and $c_i = 1$ for $1 \le i \le r_1$ and $c_i = 2$ for $r_1+1 \le i \le r_2$. Let $L: R^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^r, \varepsilon \mapsto (c_1 \log |\varepsilon^{(1)}|, \dots, c_r \log |\varepsilon^{(r)}|)$. I have seen that $L$ is a homomorphism and $\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_r$ are independent (in $(R^\times, \cdot)$) iff $L(\varepsilon_1), \dots L(\varepsilon_r)$ are independent (in ($\mathbb{R}^n, +)$).

Furthermore $\varepsilon_i \in R^\times$ with $\varepsilon_i^{(i)} \lt 0$ and $\varepsilon_i^{(j)} \gt 0$ for $i \neq j$ can be constructed. Then (in my lecture) a proof was given that these units are independent – along with a remark that alternatively one could have used $L$ to prove that.

However I wonder how to do that. Matrices with negative main diagonals and otherwise positive elements are not necessarily invertible; example: $\begin{pmatrix} -1 &1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

So is there a way "using $L$" to prove the independence of $\varepsilon_i$?

PS: The lecture was hold in German, I hope I have translated all the "vocabulary" correctly.

Comment: You say $r_2$ is the number of zeros with positive imaginary part, but it should the number of zeros with *nonzero* imaginary part, i.e., nonreal roots. Your definition of $L(\varepsilon)$ has the same first and last coordinates, and you never defined what $\varepsilon^{(i)}$ means. You should also clarify the different meaning of your two uses of independent: the $\varepsilon_i$ are "multiplicatively independent units" while the $L(\varepsilon_i)$ are "linearly independent vectors." Another typo: your list of $L$-values in the second paragraph begins and ends with $L(\varepsilon_1)$.

Comment: @KCd: Thanks, i fixed the typos and explained the meaning of $\varepsilon^{(i)}$. However, $r_2$ should denote only half of the nonreal zeros, so that part was correct (but maybe misunderstandable.)